# Accessing inner object property without inheritance

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a objects.I want to set the value for that inner objects.

**Question** I want to set the value and print `name` of class `Case`
My code -

```
public class Case
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Myclass
{
    public Case C { get; set; }
}
class Hello
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Myclass obj = new Myclass();
        string val = obj.C.name = "Testing";
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Problem**-I am getting null exception.

Any suggestion?

Comment: obj.C is never set to a value during construction

After "creating obj", you have to "create C" aswell on this obj with obj.C = new Case();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `Case` first:

```
obj.C = new Case() ;
string value = obj.C.name = "Testing";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate `C` when you create an instance of `MyClass`. Something like

```
public class Case
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Myclass
{
    public Myclass(string name) { C = new Case(); C.name = name; }
    public Case C { get; set; }
}
class Hello
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Myclass obj = new Myclass("Testing");
        string val = obj.C.name;
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `obj.C` is a complex property You need to instantiate `obj.C` as well like below,

```
Myclass obj = new Myclass();
obj.C = new Case();
string val = obj.C.name = "Testing";
Console.WriteLine(val);
Console.ReadLine();
```